# SSO on public website: how detect if a user is local or not

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml

I'm currently integrating SSO (SAML) in a public website which allows local users from a specific network to be automatically logged in, and public users to log in using forms authentication. When a user is logged in, he sees the website as everybody, but has an admin menu which allows him to navigate to the backend.

In order to know which authentication process to follow, I need to know server side if the user is indeed a local user from that network, or just a public user.

Is here any proper technique which can help me determine? How is it usually done when you host a public website with local SSO? By getting the list of public IP addresses of their network? By resource detection using the client's browser?

Comment: I assume by "automatically logged in" you mean Windows Authentication? It will depend on whether the user can provide you a valid access token (if Windows Authentication then it will be a Kerberos token) in response to the site's initial 401 challenge. If they can't then they would need to log in another way. You may want to use something like ADFS to implement such a requirement.

Comment: I added more information to my original question. Basically, the website is publicly accessible and when logged in, you have an admin menu. This admin menu must appear automatically when the SSO user loads any of the public pages, without first having to click a login link or icon. So the pages themselves are public, the admin menu on it isn't. I want to know if the user is local, or public in my code, so that I can present him/her respectively the SSO flow, or a login link where external admin users can click on to bring up the login form, without any delay. We're using SAML 2.0.

Comment: like I said this should be handled _outside_ your application by an identity provider such as ADFS. That provider will handle the login part including showing a form if necessary. Your application will then just receive an auth token telling it who the user is, just as it does when using Windows Authentication only.

Answer (score 0):

The most typical solution is to basically compare IP addresses and then decide which method of authentication should be used. It doesn't matter who executes or handles the authentication piece, whether you or some other SSO solution or IdP. At the end of the day, local vs external comes to you establishing a rule and condition that makes that distinction, and that rule is typically based on IP patterns, which would need to be implemented by you or the SSO/IdP solution.

This solution is not without caveats as IP addresses can be spoofed. So YMMV.

Also note that there is a thing called SPNEGO, that primarily works with Windows-based authentication scenarios inside workstations (think Library or Lab) coupled with Active Directory. Any "local" user able to take advantage of SPNEGO by tightly tapping into that Windows/AD environment should be able to "invisibly" login, while external users outside SPNEGO can use the forms-based authn and SAML. This might be *one solution* given the above assumptions, and most SSO/IdP solutions provide support for SPNEGO.

Note that in either case, SPNEGO is not for the faint-hearted to develop and/or configure.